# Extracting Paragraph from a news article by div class name

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to extract news article from [link](http://www.ndtv.com/world-news/apple-paid-ceo-tim-cook-10-3-million-in-2015-1263130).
I use the following code to extract with its class name. I'm pretty sure that the specific class exists but it fails to get the contents. The same code works for other similar sites.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(newsLink).get();
Elements element = document.getElementsByClass("ins_storybody");
story = element.text();
```

Comment: please post some more details

Comment: Have you checked the class exists?  Try reviewing the source of the linked webpage.

Comment: I'm trying to get the news post from the above link in my Android app using jsoup lib...the website has the div class with the specified name but it fails to extract... The same java code that I have used work for other similar site

Comment: Yes the class exists...pls have a look to verify..if I'm going wrong somewhere

Comment: Not familiar with `jsoup` but the native function `document.getElementsByClass` might need to be `document.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this CSS selector:

```
#ins_storybody
```

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(newsLink).get();
Element element = document.getElementById("#ins_storybody").first();
if (element==null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate story in: " + newsLink);
}
story = element.text();
```

The `element` can be retrieved like below too:

```
Element element = document.getElementById("ins_storybody");
```

Comment: U mean like this ....Elements element = doc.getElementsByClass("#ins_storybody");

Comment: Hey Stephen, can u answer my this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/34670312/5750634

Comment: @a_lmukthar Sorry, I don't know this API.

Comment: Ohk,please forward it to someone who may know if u can...its important for me

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why your solution does not work, but if you use the css selector functionality it should work:

```
String story = document.select("div.ins_storybody").text();
```

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Both of the below have worked for myself

```
Document doc= Jsoup.connect("http://www.ndtv.com/world-news/apple-paid-ceo-tim-cook-10-3-million-in-2015-1263130").get();
Elements element = doc.getElementsByClass("ins_storybody");
String text= element.text();
System.out.println(text);


Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ndtv.com/world-news/apple-paid-ceo-tim-cook-10-3-million-in-2015-1263130").get();
String text  = doc.select("div.ins_storybody").text();
System.out.println(text);
```

Have you checked to make sure that you have provided the correct url? Try print out the 'doc' variable to your console, this should hold the contents of the webpage.

Comment: but it still sucks for me,dont know the actual reason...any how thanks for your help!