# How to retrieve disconnect cause of android call?

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager, disconnect

I have registered a broadcast receiver for `PHONE_STATE` so whenever a call is disconnected I can execute code. I am trying to find the cause of the disconnection which I believe it can be found by calling `Call.Details.getDisconnectCause`. The problem is how can I retrieve and instance of class `Call` relating to the call which was just disconnected.

Here are some links which I have seen but haven't found the solution yet:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639882/using-android-api23-call-and-call-details-class-to-get-disconnect-cause-for-call)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670312/how-to-detect-a-call-drop-in-android)

Thank you